# Cmake does not find include /libaries (SDL2, GLEW,...)

Tags: c++, cmake, vtk, glew

I want to include SDL2 and GLEW to my Cmake project

The scr files are in C:\libs\src and I createt all the libaries in CMAKE with PATH CMAKE_Install_PRÄFIX like in this documentation:

1. Download and install CMake ( https://cmake.org/ ) and Visual Studio Community Edition ( https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/de/ )
2. Create a directory **libs** or **libraries** (whatever suits you) where you install all your libraries. It is reasonable to have this on a low level as in the future you might want to add further libraries and use this folder also for other projects. The following explanations assume that you use **C:/libs**. If you want to use another directory, just adapt the directory the way you need it.
3. Add **C:/libs** and **C:/libs/bin** to the Environment Variable *Path* ( https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm ).
4. Create a subdirectory **libs/src**, copy all the libraries from **cgAdvancedFramework/deps/** to this folder and extract them.
5. SDL2:

   - Open cmake-gui

     - Source code: **C:/libs/src/SDL2-2.0.12**
     - Binaries: **C:/libs/src/SDL2-2.0.12/build**
     - Add entry

       - Name: CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX
       - Type: PATH
       - Value: **C:\libs**
       - Ok
     - Configure

       - Accept creating build directory
       - Use default native compiler --> Finish
     - Generate
     - Open Project (this should start Visual Studio)
   - Visual Studio

     - Solution Configuration: Debug
     - right-click ALL_BUILD --> Build (if errors appear, here you might have done something wrong before)
     - right-click INSTALL --> Build (if errors appear, ...)
     - do the same for Solution Configuration: RelWithDebInfo (optional but recommended)

My Project is locatet C:\Users\Documents...\dvs\volren

and the build dir is locatet
C:\Users\Documents...\dvs\build and

C:\libs\include\GL

C:\libs\include\SDL2
...

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#pragma once
#define NOMINMAX
#include <SDL2.h>   //dont find
#include <GL/glew.h> //dont find
#include <vtk3DS.h> // find
```

CMakelist.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

PROJECT(volren)

find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
include(${VTK_USE_FILE})

find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS})

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(volren MACOSX_BUNDLE main.cpp Camera.hpp Math.hpp Image.hpp)

target_link_libraries(volren ${VTK_LIBRARIES} ${GLEW_LIBRARIES} ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
```

Error: Can not open source file GL/glew.h

Where is my mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are on Windows, so why add `MACOSX_BUNDLE` in your `add_executable` ?

Also, are you sure `GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS`, `SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS` are the correct variable to use ? Did you check if they were populated ?

Comment: What do you mean with "populated"
I hope `GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS, SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS` are the correct variable to use , but i dit not know 100%.

Comment: By populated, I mean, is there anything inside, when you print them do they actually have the expected value ?

Comment: Ok I testet it
`SDL2_FIND` works but `SDL_INCLUDE_DIRS` is empty 

 `VDK_USE_FILE` works

Comment: Ok, so if it find SDL2 but ``SDL_INCLUDE_DIRS`` is empty, maybe this is not the correct variable to use. I think you can find the correct variable by going into the ``FindSDL2.cmake`` file.